# Trouble with Azure OAuth2 integration in Golang

Tags: azure, go, oauth-2.0, access-token

I am currently working on integrating Azure OAuth2 authentication into my Golang application. Everything seems to work fine for the initial login, but I'm facing an issue when a user logs out and then attempts to log in again, or when a second user tries to log in. The problem I'm encountering is that I cannot fetch the token after logout, and it results in an error.

> "oauth2: cannot fetch token: 404 Not Found\nResponse: "

I would appreciate any assistance or guidance on how to resolve this issue and make the Azure OAuth2 integration work smoothly for multiple users and login attempts.

I'm expecting it to return

```
 {
   "access_token":"2YotnFZFEjr1zCsicMWpAA",
   "token_type":"example",
   "expires_in":3600,
   "refresh_token":"tGzv3JOkF0XG5Qx2TlKWIA"
 }
```

Comment: Make sure that there is no cache issue